# How can I import or use SF Pro in VS code? Using a Mac

Tags: css, ios, visual-studio-code, fonts

I've downloaded the latest Apple fonts but I can't figure out how to import them and use them in my web dev project in VS Code.

Is it even possible? If yes, how can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just so you know, there are limitations on the fonts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32178596/14351818

Comment: I am confused, do you want to use the font in the project or in the editor?